# Show that the sequence converges to a limit $L$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

> Let $k>1$ and define a sequence $\left\{a_{n}\right\}$ by $a_{1}=1$ and $$a_{n+1}=\frac{k\left(1+a_{n}\right) }{\left(k+a_{n}\right)}$$ 
>   (a) Show that $\left\{a_{n}\right\}$ converges.
>   (b) Find $\lim a_{n}$

I have no problem finding the limit by taking the limit of both sides and then solving for $L$. I am not sure how to go about showing that it does in fact converge?

I tried induction on the recurrence but am unable to find a better form.

**Edit:**

Assume $a_n \geq a_{n-1}$ then $a_{n+1} = \frac{k(1+a_n)}{k+a_n} \geq \frac{k(1+a_{n-1})}{k+a_n}....$

Comment: Two possible approaches: show that the sequence is Cauchy, or show that it is monotone increasing and bounded above.

Comment: It seems like monotone increasing is the easier way to go. However, when I try and do it by strong induction it is not clear how to go about it, since there is an $a_{n}$ in the denominator that I am not sure what to do with.

Comment: @Math1000 see edit

Comment: Or, assume that the limit exists and take limit to the recursive formula to find the limit candidate $L$, which is $L=\sqrt{k}$. Using this guess, we can try to estimate the difference between $a_n$ and $\sqrt{k}$. Using the recursive formula, check that $$|a_{n+1}-\sqrt{k}| \leq \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)|a_n - \sqrt{k}|.$$ From this, conclude that $a_n \to \sqrt{k}$.

Comment: As for the monotonicity approach, notice that $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{k-a_n^2}{k+a_n}\qquad\text{and}\qquad a_{n+1}-\sqrt{k}=\frac{k-\sqrt{k}}{k+a_n}(a_{n}-\sqrt{k}).$$ Together with the induction, show that $0<a_{n}\leq a_{n+1}\leq\sqrt{k}$ holds for all $n$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I am having difficulty using induction to prove this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating the recurrence relation, it is easy to check that

$$ a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{k-a_n^2}{k+a_n}\qquad\text{and}\qquad a_{n+1}-\sqrt{k}=\frac{k-\sqrt{k}}{k+a_n}(a_{n}-\sqrt{k}). \tag{*}$$

Now we inductively prove the following claim.

> **Claim.** both $0 \leq a_n \leq \sqrt{k}$ and $[(n = 1) \text{ or } (a_{n-1} \leq a_n) ]$ hold for all $n \geq 1$.

(*Remark.* The weird logical connective $[(n = 1) \text{ or } (a_{n-1} \leq a_n) ]$ is introduced simply because it makes the proof shorter. Indeed, this allows us to ignore the inequality $a_{n-1} \leq a_n$ when $n = 1$. One can as well work with a more natural claim $0 \leq a_n \leq a_{n+1} \leq \sqrt{k}$, but this may result in repeating the same argument in both the base step and the induction step.)

- **Base case.** When $n = 1$, we only need to check whether $0 \leq a_1 \leq \sqrt{k}$ holds or not, which is obvious from the assumption on $a_1$ and $k$.
- **Induction step.** Assume that the claim holds for $n \geq 1$. Then we know that $0 \leq a_n \leq \sqrt{k}$. Now the first identity of $\text{(*)}$ shows

  $$a_{n+1} - a_{n} = \frac{k-a_n^2}{k+a_n^2} \geq 0$$

  and hence $a_{n+1} \geq a_n \geq 0$. Also, the second identity tells that

  $$a_{n+1}-\sqrt{k}=\frac{k-\sqrt{k}}{k+a_n}(a_n-\sqrt{k}) \leq 0,$$

  and so, $a_{n+1} \leq \sqrt{k}$. Combining altogether, we have proved that $0 \leq a_{n+1} \leq \sqrt{k}$ and $ a_n \leq a_{n+1}$. So the induction step is established.

Therefore by the principle of mathematical induction, the claim holds for all $n$ and hence $(a_n)$ is non-decreasing and bounded.